# Зачем нужны указатели?

Tags: c++, указатели

Oбъяcнитe, зaчeм нyжны yкaзaтeли?

Heт, я пoнял пpинцип paбoты, нo нe пoнял oднoгo - ЗAЧEM? Зaчeм paбoтaть c фyнкциями-члeнaми, пepeмeнными пo ccылкe, ecли я мoгy paбoтaть c ними нaпpямyю?

Comment: Если Вы не поняли "зачем", значит Вы не поняли указатели!

Comment: Посмотрите, например, man qsort (это очень полезная функция сортировки), подумайте как это можно запрограммировать и многое прояснится.

Comment: qsort реализуется и без указателей. Например в таких языках как lisp/haskell, где указателей (по крайней мере в явном виде) нет.
На плюсах можно без указателей тоже сделать, но только памяти будет больше потребляться.

Comment: Какой смысл биться за лишние сто байт памяти?

Comment: В скорости дело...

Comment: To @KoVadim, вопрос о C++ (C). Про Lisp можно считать, что указателей нет, а можно, что все кроме atom это указатель. Потом, речь не об алгорите QuickSort, а о конкретной библиотечной реализации.

To @Xyanight, а если речь о сотнях мегабайт ?

--

Вообще складывается впечатление, что вопрос скорее об  ООП.

Comment: На самом деле все намного проще, указатели нужны для того чтобы писать "волшебные" коды, быстрые и непанятные. + для того чтобы те кто не знает С++ думали что С++ это что-то неимоверно сложное :D
Использовать х надо потому, что в они есть и твой код становится более непонятным.
****
PS:Как мне показалось - объяснил на вашем нынешнем уровне
****
PPS:не трольте коммент ибо коммент сам по себе троллинг :D

Comment: ты пользуешься string'ом или vector'ом???
или может быть даже stack использовал???
так вот без указателей ты это не реализуешь!!!

Comment: Смелое заявление. Если имеются в виду стандартные библиотеки (STL) -- то да. Если нет -- то можно и без указателей (используя родственные указателям индексы массивов)

Comment: Ваш звонок очень важен для нас! [Вас услышали )](https://habr.com/post/352570/)

Comment: Как раз наоборот. Указатели всё упрощают.

Comment: А ничего, что индексы указателям противоположны? А вот любые два других понятия как раз более родственны.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"Если кто-то зажигает звезды, значит, это кому-нибудь нужно"

Вот такой пример. Положим, Вы передаете в функцию какую-то переменную. Там с ее значением что-то делается, и новое значение должно быть занесено в ту переменную, значение которой Вы в функцию передали. Если сделаете что-то типа этого

```
void func (int a) {
  a += 10;
}    
......    
int i = 2;
func(i);
```

То значение переменной i не изменится, потому что в функцию передается копия этой переменной и с ней производятся операции. А если передать указатель или ссылку на эту переменную, то получите доступ к ней и можете изменять ее значение

```
void func (int* a) {
  *a += 10;
}    
......    
int i = 2;
func(&i);
```

Если нужно передать в функцию структуру или объект, то передавать его целиком можно, но это может отнять кучу памяти и времени, ведь они могут быть очень большими. В простых примерах это незаметно, но в реальных программах, где это может повторяться тысячи и миллионы раз, тормоза будут огромные. Вместо этого передаете указатель или ссылку и получаете из функции доступ к объекту.

Уже говорили о динамическом выделении памяти. Если еще про это не читали, то прочитаете. Там без указателей В ПРИНЦИПЕ не обойтись.

Это лишь несколько примеров. Чем глубже будете вникать в С++, тем больше об этом узнаете.

И еще. Не думайте, что программисты до Вас были дураками.

Answer (score 10):

Указатели применяют:

1. Для возврата нескольких значений из функции. В качестве аргумента передаётся указатель на переменную, функция записывает туда значение. Такой подход очень распространён в DirectX, OpenGL, Windows API и других библиотеках в стиле C. Для этого можно использовать и ссылки, но не рекомендуется, так как синтаксис передачи и возврата неотличим.
2. Для хранения адреса динамически выделенной памяти. Она отличается от обычной тем, что программист сам регулирует время жизни объектов, и её больше (а размер стека всего порядка мегабайта). Если адрес будет потерян, то память нельзя будет ни использовать, ни освободить. Возникнет утечка памяти.
3. C-строка представляет собой указатель на её первый символ.
4. Для создания различных структур данных: связанных списков, деревья и т. д.
5. Для передачи аргумента в функцию без копирования (и вызова конструктора для объектов), которое может оказаться долгим для сложных объектов. Правда, здесь лучше использовать константные ссылки.

Таким образом, примений указателей очень много.

Comment: @Xyanight, вспомните, что массивы в Си представляются указателями (даже не в случае параметров). 

Например:

    int a[10], *b = a+5;
    ...
    printf ("%d\n",b[0]);  // распечатает значение a[5]


Вообще указатели в Си позволяют писать более обобщенный код.

Comment: В качестве аргумента передаётся указатель на переменную, функция записывает туда значение.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем нужны почтовые адреса? Можно же общаться сразу с людьми. Но иногда приходится поручать доставку письма почтальону, которому надо сначала сказать, куда конкретно он должен доставить письмо, так как **один и тот же** почтальон должен уметь **единообразно для адресанта** доставлять письма **всем адресатам**. Как? Лезть в его днк нельзя, нельзя его даже переучивать. Указатель – это такая величина, в которой можно хранить адрес. А ссылка – это нечто, ведущее себя как указатель, но имеющее при этом синтаксис сразу целевой величины, которую мы по этому адресу ищем. То есть поле на конверте с адресом Пети, притворяющееся самим Петей. На это поле на конверте можно наорать вместо Пети, а обидится Петя. По указателю же можно только нанять хулигана, поручив ему наорать на Петю. Совсем же по-другому выглядит, а результат тот же. В одном случае мы голос посрвали, в другом – **явно** послали посредника. Но по указателю можно послать: почтальона, шпиона, хулигана и киллера, а по ссылке – только наорать на адрес на конверте, спокойно ему что-то сказать или поглазеть прямо на Петин стол, но киллеры даже не поймут, чего от них хотят, а сами мы убивать не умеем.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы выделять большое количество памяти. Советую прочитать про стек и кучу (heap). На стеке при большом объеме данных будет происходить переполнение.

Comment: Вот именно! Автору вопроса нужно смотреть в сторону размерных и ссылочных типов данных, как они устроены, какие отличия, где хранятся, зачем их разделили и тд. К чему тут тролинг............

Comment: Нeт, я пoнял пpинцип paбoты, нo нe пoнял oднoгo - ЗAЧEM


Малеха противоречивый бред? Не находите?

Comment: Согласен - автор не разобрался в данной теме!

Comment: @AlexWindHope ну значит плохо объясняли

Comment: void fn(int *pintArg}  
    {  
    *pintPrg  =  10;  
}  

    void parent(void)      
    {  
    int  n = 0;  
    fn(&n);  
    }    
А вы не находите этот код бредовым?

Comment: >А вы не находите этот код бредовым?

 Нахожу. Компилятор такое не скомпилирует. У функции fn нет закрывающей скобки. Не вижу звёздочек - парсер проглотил?

 Ещё, непонятна цель этого кода. Название функции fn и её параметр ни о чём не говорят.

 И вообще, это неудачный пример использования указателей в плане того, что он не показывает их полезность.

Comment: Покажите хоть одну "полезность"? Также полезность public и private? Кто, как не программист, контролирует доступ к переменным класса? И какая-то там иллюзорная "защита" кажется просто смешной... От кого??? От самого себя? Или программа сама вдруг захочет что-либо изменить по своему желанию?!

Comment: Точно, вопрос **не об указателях**, а о дурацком преподавании ООП.

Comment: public и private предполагает что код может быть использовн кем-то еще, кто может залезть своими руками куда не надо и все поломать.

Comment: >public и private предполагает что код может быть использовн кем-то еще, кто может залезть своими руками куда не надо и все поломать.

 Только если пользователь очень захочет, он всё равно сможет залезть и всё поломать. Например, задефайнить private на public, и делать, что захочет.

Comment: словосочетание **Good Parts** вам о чем-то говорит? Судя по вашим комментариям - нет

Comment: Поисковик мне подсказывает что словосочетание Good Parts как-то связано с JavaScript (или с деталями для автомобилей:)). Честно говоря, не читал.

Comment: Зачем нужны указатели...  
а куда без них????